# Get the value of the ID of the video that you click on

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I added several videos from the data base, and each video has its own ID.

I want when i click on the video, it takes its ID and put it in DataBase.

I did a lot of things to get to the ID value of each video, but couldn't solve it.
I saw many of the same problems on this site and was unable to solve my problem

Please help me

```
  <?php session_start() ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    

  <div class="container mt-5 mb-3" '>
      <div class="row">
 
          <?php
          include('db.php');
          $q='select * from ruby'; // Fetch video from DB
          $query = mysqli_query($conn , $q);
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){  ?>   
     

          <div class="col-md-4">
              <video poster="../img/ruby.png" class="video"   width='100%' controls muted  id="<?php 
               echo $row["id"]; ?>"  >
               <source src="<?php echo 'video/' .  $row['name']; ?>" >
              </video>   
          </div>
        
          <?php }  ?>  

      </div>
  </div>
```

in same page ..........

```
        <?php 
        $dbserver = "localhost";
        $dbuser = "root";
        $dbpass = "";
        $dbname = "watch";
        
        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbserver , $dbuser , $dbpass , $dbname);
        if(!$conn){
            echo 'connection failed!';
        } 
        
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
        
        
        $q = "insert into ruby  values(' $id' , ' $name' , '/* Here I want to put the video ID*/' )";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn , $q);
        
        ?>

     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: To perform something like this, you should research AJAX, since an asynchronous process that doesn't interrupt the video is the only thing that makes sense. You would need to attach an event listener to your video that detects playback has started and then trigger the AJAX that stores what you need into the database.

Comment: _"I did a lot of things to get to the ID value of each video"_ - None of those attempts is in your question. Add at least the most promising one, explain what problems you have with that attempt and what errors you get, preferable as a [mcve]

Comment: [xkcd: Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/) -> https://bobby-tables.com/